# How do you wash nylon grain bags for first use?

Tags: equipment, biab, beginner, boil-equipment

Got some food grade nylon bags.  They smell a little plasticy. How do i wash them and get then ready before using them for boil in a bag brewing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Toss them in the laundry with your whites. 
No farbric softner.
Then air dry.

Comment: You can also toss it in with some baking soda.  That may help with the smell.  But not laundry detergent!  I perform the same routine to clean the bag after use.  Hang to dry, and you are good to go!

Comment: Basically what I got from most of the answers was just wash them. What I wound up doing is soaking them in hot water with some unscented dishwasher powder (Seventh Generation) then soaked them in clean warm water then rinsed a couple of times in cold water. Allowed them to air dry indoors. Smell went away. Didn't have any laundry to do but your idea is the easiest which is why I'm selecting it.

Answer (score 3):

No soap. Don't weaken them in the sun. Just drop in PBW for at least  1/2hr. Rinse in hot water (at least as hot as the water was when you started soaking it). Drip dry

Comment: Nylon is pretty resistant to UV light that's why they use it for dock lines.

Answer (score 2):

A good old fashioned hot water soak, a brewing sanitiser and sun bleach to dry will do the trick. Sometimes that plastic smell you describe is impossible to completely get rid of though. At least you can remove any surface residues from the plastic though.

Answer (score 2):

Boil new bag in water for a few minutes. Dry in microwave. Clean. Sterile. Done.
Repeat for next use.

Comment: I agree - to reduce the "new bag" smell boil the bag in water for a few minutes. If the bag is new this will boil off any volatile chemicals from the plastic and also dissolve any remaining contaminants that might affect the subsequent brews. I rarely use a detergent but PBW or VWP have helped shift stains by soaking after use.

Answer (score 0):

I never do anything to my grain bags. I was always taught that whatever goes into the pot doesn't need sanitizing because we boil it anyway. After use, I just wash them out with plain water.